# How to delete Duplicate values in a column but only between the empty rows in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

[Sample data: Click to get image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NbQI.jpg)

I need to delete duplicate values in the column for Distance, that is column I. There are empty rows between each group.
I want to keep just the topmost value present in each group. Note that the column may have similar values in different groups that shouldn't be deleted.
Here is what I tried. But it deletes useful values if the value is the same between different groups(as code would but that's not what I want).

```
Dim colJ As Range
    Set colJ = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("J")
    
    For i = 2 To lr
        If .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells(i - 1, 11) Then
          .Cells(i, 11) = ""
        End If
   
        If .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells(i + 2, 11) Then
          .Cells(i + 2, 11) = ""
        End If
   
        If .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells(i + 3, 11) Then
          .Cells(i + 3, 11) = ""
        End If
   
        If .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells(i + 4, 11) Then
          .Cells(i + 4, 11) = ""
        End If
   
        If .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells(i + 5, 11) Then
          .Cells(i + 4, 11) = ""
        End If
   
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub DeleteGroupDuplicates()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rng As Range, A As Range
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet    'use here the necessary sheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("I" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of "I:I"
   
   'create a discontinuous range, in order to create areas between empty rows:

   Set rng = sh.Range("I2:I" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
   For Each A In rng.Areas  'iterate between all areas (intervals between empty rows)
        A.UnMerge
        A.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 'remove duplicates, no header...
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Akhil Hothi Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: I am trying to resolve some errors... Actually There are merged cells in first column and also I just want to delete duplicate values in column I.

Comment: When I make columns:=9 in last line of code, then it shows run time error 1004

Comment: @Akhil Hothi Does it work in "I:I", as your question was pointing? The column number **does  not mean the column as you see it on the sheet**! It is the column number **of the range**. If you try the code for only J:J column, you should use also 1, because the range has only one column...

Comment: Yes it isn't working... I just want to delete values in the cells not entire cells or rows. And plz do note that there are some merged cells in initial columns that might show error like this "This action can not be done on merged cells" or "All merged cells should be same size for this action"

Comment: @Akhil Hothi And, I will like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works. Only after testing the code **as it is** and confirming that it works, you should try modifying it and ask for clarifications if it does not do what you expect from it... Now I am leaving my office. If you need further clarifications, I will be able to supply them after some hours, when I will be at home...

Comment: @Akhil Hothi Of course! It does not work on merged cells and you should mention that in your question. It can be made to firstly unmerge the cells, but I do not have time to do it now. I am leaving...

Comment: Are the merged cells on the same column, or are they  extended to other culumns?

Comment: Meged cells are present in column A only.

Comment: Please do some help

Comment: @Akhil Hothi OK. When you say "Meged cells are present in column A only" should I understand that they are only on the column rows? I mean, something like "A3:A6", "A8:A9"? Or they start from column A:A but extend to other cells, like "A2:C2", "A4:D5" etc.? If only on the column rows, I can rapidly adapt the code. Now, if this is the case, unmerging cells is convenient for you?

Comment: @Akhil Hothi Please, test the updated code. It will work only if the merged cells are **on the same column rows**... Please, test it and send some feedback.